# Power Tools Renaming "Author - Title" to "Title (Author)"

Tags: batch-rename

I want to use Power Toys' Power Rename utility to rename some PDFs that have their filenames in the form of "Author - Title" to "Title (Author)".

Can anyone help me with the regular expression to achieve this?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/powerrename

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation in your link, regular expressions are
supported.

You may replace `(.+) - (.+)` by `$2 ($1)`.

Comment: Worked great! Thanks!